# Progress bar percentage align with bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a progress bar, currently the percentage are shown in right side, but now I want the percentage able to follow the bar, no matter the blue bar is short or long.

**Example that I expect**

[image]

---

```css
.popup_survey_whitebox_percent {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #F30;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar {
  background: #444;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner {
  background: #0CF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup_survey_whitebox_percent" class="popup_survey_whitebox_percent">75%</div>
<br>
<div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar">
  <div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner" style="width:75%;"></div>
</div>
<div id="popup_survey_whitebox_percent" class="popup_survey_whitebox_percent">15%</div>
<br>
<div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar">
  <div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner" style="width:15%;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML:**

Move `popup_survey_whitebox_percent` inside `popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner`:

```
<div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar">
    <div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner" style="width:75%;">
        <div id="popup_survey_whitebox_percent" class="popup_survey_whitebox_percent">75%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

Change `margin-top` of `popup_survey_whitebox_percent`:

```
.popup_survey_whitebox_percent{
    float:right;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#F30;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0cx9w1m3/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `margin-left` of the percentage values equal to the `width` of the progress bar.

```js
$('.popup_survey_whitebox_percent').each(function() {
  $(this).css('margin-left', $(this).next().next().find('.popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner').css('width'));
});
```

```css
.popup_survey_whitebox_percent {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #F30;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar {
  background: #444;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner {
  background: #0CF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup_survey_whitebox_percent">75%</div>
<br />
<div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar">
  <div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner" style="width:75%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="popup_survey_whitebox_percent">15%</div>
<br />
<div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar">
  <div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner" style="width:15%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
you only need to put your text percentage tag inside the progressbar html tag

```
div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar">
  <div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner" style="width:75%;">
      <span id="popup_survey_whitebox_percent" class="popup_survey_whitebox_percent">75%</span>
<br>
      </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar">
  <div class="popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner" style="width:15%;">
      <span id="popup_survey_whitebox_percent" class="popup_survey_whitebox_percent">15%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/e4wvyamh/